# Bullets HTML code are bigger on some devices

Tags: html, css

I have a template and I'm using some circles using this code: `&#9679;`

I don't know why on some devices is bigger than others. For example on iPhone and on a HTC A9 looks like I want, but i've tried on Samsung Galaxy s6 Edge and the bullet is too big.

I've tried to put the code on `<span>, <p>` and it's the same thing... maybe resolutions issue?

Comment: Hi, it is just font issue, default font for diferent devices is just diferent.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid this proble try to make all devices use the same font.

Comment: how can I check that? to see..what font i'm using on S6..and what font on HTC for example..

Comment: a)  you can set preferable font fot your aplication and some fallbacks
b) If it is a website you can add font and ask browser to use it 
according to this link 
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face